# boost::last_write_time returns the wrong value on every first call after file modification(file in network drive connected through VPN)

Tags: c++, macos, boost, stat, boost-filesystem

I am using `boost::last_write_time` as one of my checks to see if a file has been modified or not.
The call works fine if the file I am using is a local file.
But if I request the same information for a **file from a network drive**, I get wrong result.

The call I make is : **`boost::filesystem::last_write_time( file_path )`**

I am connected to the drive through **VPN**. The result is **wrong only for the first time** I make a request after modifying the file. The next call returns the right time.
The wrong time I get is always the old modification time(the one prior to the new change).

It doesn't matter if I wait a while before making the request. The first time is always wrong and the second time I get the correct one.

I am working on a mac. And I see that internally the method makes use of `stat` function.

I tried passing the `error_code` struct to see if there was any error. But it held 0 after the call.

Is there any limitation related to getting status of files over a network using `stat` method?

Is there any function that I could call to ensure that the `last_write_method` always returns the right time(other than calling the method twice)?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Found some additional info on: [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/stat.htm)

In usage notes, bullet 6 on "Network File System Differences" says:

> Local access to remote files through the Network File System may produce unexpected results due to conditions at the server...
> ...The local Network File System also impacts operations that retrieve file attributes. Recent changes at the server may not be available at your client yet, and old values may be returned from operations. (Several options on the Add Mounted File System (ADDMFS) command determine the time between refresh operations of local data.)

But I still don't understand why the call works correctly the second time, even when the call is made immediately after the first one.

And why it doesn't work if I wait for some time before I make the first call.

Comment: Run `strace` and see if you can't figure something out from there. You should be able to localize the issue.

Comment: @TomTrebicky Thank you. I saw that for Mac we have dtrace and dtruss as alternatives for strace. But the versions of Mac OS starting from El Capitan seems to have put some security restriction that prevents me from running these trace over an application. I saw some articles that helps with overcoming these restrictions. But I wasn't sure if it was a safe thing to do. There were comments in those articles warning that the change might leave my device vulnerable.

Comment: Aaah right, on MacOS it would be `dtruss`. If you can’t make it work, I would suggest installing linux in a VM and run it there.